# In Linux, how to stop 'date -s' from assigning 00:00 time on empty input

Tags: linux, bash, date

I bought a new laptop, but for some reason the built-in clock is loosing 15 min per day. The company I bought it from replaced the CMOS battery, but that didn't make a difference. I ended up putting the following in my Ubuntu crontab:

```
*   *   *   *   *   date -s "$(wget -S  "http://www.google.com/" 2>&1 | grep -E '^[[:space:]]*[dD]ate:' | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*[dD]ate:[[:space:]]*//' | head -1l | awk '{print $1, $3, $2,  $5 ,"GMT", $4 }' | sed 's/,//')"
```

It works great (at least until I'm in a GMT timezone, as Google returns GMT time) when I have Internet connection, but when I'm offline it sets the time to the current date 00:00am. That is `date -s ""` changes the time to 00:00.

Is there some flag I can pass to `date` to tell it don't bother changing anything on empty input? Or modify the other parts of the cron job?

Comment: You may want to look into `ntpdate`.

Comment: Maybe you could write a script that checks whether you're online before running `date -s`? BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Comment: Hi @JamesBrown, I can't use ntpdate, as port 123 is blocked by a firewall at my work. There is some sort of ntp working over https, but I couldn't get that working.

Comment: @wjandrea i'm not sure how to execute an if statement in a crontab job, otherwise i could probably check if the outcome from the staff in brackets is empty.

Comment: @AccessDenied I mean write a script that does everything, and call the script from the crontab

Comment: Ahhhh, what a great idea, i'll give that a try.

Comment: Please, *please* use `ntpd` instead (`ntpdate` for big jumps, `ntpd` for ongoing maintenance). `ntpd` tries to adjust the clock in ways that are less likely to induce bugs in software you're running (as tend to happen with larger jumps, jumps backward, etc), and it can poll multiple time servers, track connectivity, reliability and trustworthiness, maintain internal knowledge about how much clock drift you typically have, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need conditionality in a crontab line, it's really executing everything using bourne shell and so you can use shell conditionals "&&" and "||"

```
* * * * *  foo=$(wget...) ; test -z "$foo" || date -s "$foo"
```

Assign your blat output to 'foo' .. test if foo is empty, if not empty use it to set the date